# Wordpress Metabox

Tags: wordpress

Я пытался найти в интернете, но не смог найти подходящего решения. 
Я хочу при редактировании страницы добавить второе изображение. Предоставляю  копию изображения, чего я хочу сделать:
[image: https://pp.userapi.com/c638130/v638130793/27aed/_-sFPXO9_O8.jpg]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Я хочу в редакции страницы добавить второе изображение.

Есть плагины для этого. Один из них: https://wordpress.org/plugins/dynamic-featured-image/screenshots/